# How do I disable trackback notifications on a WordPress.com blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I tried http://astroclimatology.wordpress.com/wp-admin/options-discussion.php but it didn't work. I do want unregistered users to be able to comment.

==

What I dont want is email notifications like this:

> New trackback on your post "we also analyzed zonal wind too" Website:
>   Quora (IP: 107.20.3.229 , ec2-107-20-3-229.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
>   URL    :
>   http://www.quora.com/Planetary-Science/How-can-faster-rotation-rate-lead-to-an-increased-pole-to-equator-temperature-gradient-when-the-zonal-velocity-of-the-jet-stream-decreases-as-predicted-by-both-t Excerpt: **How can faster rotation rate lead to an increased
>   pole-to-equator temperature gradient when the zonal velocity of the
>   jet stream decreases, as predicted by both the Held-Hou model of
>   circulation and one of the CAM3 simulations that I ran?...**
>
> Supposedly, faster rotation rate means a stronger Coriolis effect,
>   which means that a tropical parcel of air that goes poleward in the
>   meridional direction is more likely to be deflected in the zonal
>   direction. Yet, the Held-Hou model of circulation pr...
>
> You can see all trackbacks on this post here:

Comment: If you uncheck the box "Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks)" I think will solve your problem

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. Questions about **wordpress.com support** are explicitly out of scope, as per our FAQ.

Comment: Normally, I agree with Chip on this. But since it's the exact same answer whether you're on .ORG or .COM, I will only close this if several other people agree as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your site's dashboard.  Then navigate to Settings » Discussion and disable the "Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks)" option:

[image: Trackback Option]

Answer (score -1):

This loop disables trackbacks completely, just needs to be hooked...

```
foreach ( get_post_types() as $post_type ) {

   /* remove all trackbacks from any post types */
   remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'trackbacks' );
}
```

Or just disable trackbacks by default...

Comment: This doesn't work on wordpress.com, where you don't have access to the Wordpress files

Comment: You still can disable the "link notifications" by default ...
and might have to remove them manually from any previous posts.

Comment: I'm sorry for not having provided the button-clicker version :)